# How can I change the default path for saving figures from an interactive Jupyter shell for Python in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I often generate figures using `matplotlib`. They get displayed in the shell and there's a little "Save As" icon that lets me save them. Whenever I click on it the default path is my system's root directory "/". Every time I want to save a figure I have to click through my file system to arrive at the desired filepath (which would be Desktop). Is there a way to change this? What I've tried so far:

- running `os.chdir("/Users/clo/Desktop/")` in the active shell
- in Settings, changing Terminal > Integrated: Cwd to /Users/clo/Desktop/

EDIT:

Posted on github as a feature request: [github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13321](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13321)

Comment: does a python call work in a shell? why do you think they are in connection with the python interpreter of the Jupyter instance

Comment: The python call I listed was called within the jupyter shell. I didn't think much of it just wanted to try whatever I could think of. If this doesn't answer your question I'd need clarification on what you meant exactly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure, but it looks to me like there's no way to get this without the maintainers of the VS Code Jupyter extension changing their extension to support it.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/d674a17ee56b09ccf70b37ec5b711fd70963cf5d/src/webviews/extension-side/plotting/plotViewer.node.ts#L42

```js
    protected override async exportPlot(payload: IExportPlotRequest): Promise<void> {
        ...
        // Ask the user what file to save to
        const file = await this.applicationShell.showSaveDialog({
            saveLabel: localize.DataScience.exportPlotTitle,
            filters: filtersObject
        });
```

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/d674a17ee56b09ccf70b37ec5b711fd70963cf5d/src/platform/common/application/types.ts#L272

```js
import {
  ...
  SaveDialogOptions,
  ...
} from 'vscode';
  ...
  export interface IApplicationShell {
    ...
    /**
     * Shows a file save dialog to the user which allows to select a file
     * for saving-purposes.
     *
     * @param options Options that control the dialog.
     * @returns A promise that resolves to the selected resource or `undefined`.
     */
    showSaveDialog(options: SaveDialogOptions): Thenable<Uri | undefined>;
    ...
```

There's also another similar file that probably needs to change as well: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/blob/main/src/webviews/extension-side/plotView/plotSaveHandler.node.ts.

They'd need to contribute a user setting so you could provide a value, and then use that value in the [`SaveDialogOptions`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#SaveDialogOptions).

I did a cursory google search ("`site:github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues save plot default directory OR folder`") to see if this has already been requested as a feature, and from a quick glance, didn't see one.

Haliaetus [made a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/new?assignees=&labels=feature-request&template=3_feature_request.md) asking for this feature, which you can find here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/13321. I'm tracking it and will update this answer post as needed.

[VS Code 1.80's new `files.dialog.defaultPath` setting](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_80#_default-file-dialog-location) might be a suitable workaround, which is part of the reason the above issue ticket was closed.